# Selecting MySQL row using external counter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm making a simple program that calls data from a mySQL table. I want to have a JQuery button that if pressed, displays the next row of data in the mySQL table. Right now, I have this script which loads all the data.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('#show').load('/php/getQuestion.php')
        });

    });
</script>
```

I also have this php code which calls the data I want, but for all rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT question_id, question FROM Question";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $row["question"]."<br>";
      }
   } else {
         echo "0 results";
   }
```

My question is two-fold. How could I edit my php code to only call a certain row, and how could I specify the row from an external file (most likely .html with JQuery).

Comment: How many rows are there?

Comment: Right now, 4, but I'd like to keep adding.

Comment: Well until you get into the hundreds, I'd just select the whole dataset and handle pagination entirely within php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a single row you need to change the query, you need to add a WHERE clause to tell the query which row you want searching it by the id of the table:

```
 $sql = "SELECT question_id, question FROM Question WHERE question_id=someid";
```

To get the value you need to edit your load to:

```
$('#show').load('/php/getQuestion.php'), { name: $("#txtname").val()});
```

In this example you are passing a new variable called name via POST and sending the value of the txtname html (txtname is the id)

you can get that value on your getQuestion.php like:

```
$_POST["name"]
```

Comment: Could I write:  $sql = "SELECT question_id, question FROM Question WHERE question_id=$_POST["name"] or does $_POST["name"] have to be defined to another variable first?

Comment: See about parametrised queries